# Get pretty-printed result in Cider-evaluated expression in Emacs

Tags: emacs, clojure, cider

I'd like to insert the result of an evaluated Clojure expression directly in my Emacs buffer, in pretty-printed form.

For example, with something like:

```
    ;; [emacs lisp]
    (insert (nrepl-dict-get (nrepl-sync-request:eval "(range 30)") "value"))
```

I get, in the buffer of interest,

```
    ;;=>
    (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29)
```

In the past, I've let Clojure pretty-print things for me, as so:

```
(nrepl-dict-get
  (nrepl-sync-request:eval
    (format "(clojure.core/let [x %s] (with-out-str (clojure.pprint/pprint x)))"
            "(range 30)"))
  "value")
;;=>
"(0\n 1\n 2\n 3\n 4\n 5\n 6\n 7\n 8\n 9\n 10\n 11\n 12\n 13\n 14\n 15\n 16\n 17\n 18\n 19\n 20\n 21\n 22\n 23\n 24\n 25\n 26\n 27\n 28\n 29)\n"
```

However, the `"` and `\n` are being inserted escaped; I want them to be inserted unescaped.  In other words, I want the pretty-printed result to be inserted directly without escaping quotes or newlines.  This used to work in earlier versions of Cider and `cider-nrepl`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrapping:

```
(nrepl-dict-get
  (nrepl-sync-request:eval
    (format "(clojure.core/let [x %s] (with-out-str (clojure.pprint/pprint x)))"
            "(range 30)"))
  "value")
```

in `read` should solve this.

Answer (score 1):

I've just added this feature to [lispy](https://github.com/abo-abo/lispy) (it's a Paredit-style
package that uses Cider for Clojure eval):
<kbd>2E</kbd> will to a pretty-printed eval-and-insert, while
<kbd>E</kbd> will keep doing a plain one.

Here's an example (`|` represents point):

```
|(for [x (range 8)] (range x))
```

After <kbd>E</kbd>:

```
|(for [x (range 8)] (range x))
(() (0) (0 1) (0 1 2) (0 1 2 3) (0 1 2 3 4) (0 1 2 3 4 5) (0 1 2 3 4 5 6))
```

After <kbd>2E</kbd>:

```
|(for [x (range 8)] (range x))
(()
 (0)
 (0 1)
 (0 1 2)
 (0 1 2 3)
 (0 1 2 3 4)
 (0 1 2 3 4 5)
 (0 1 2 3 4 5 6))
```

Of course you can still do <kbd>EjM</kbd> to accomplish the same thing:

```
(for [x (range 8)] (range x))
|(()
 (0)
 (0 1)
 (0 1 2)
 (0 1 2 3)
 (0 1 2 3 4)
 (0 1 2 3 4 5)
 (0 1 2 3 4 5 6))
```